# Matlab ODE solving Error Ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations, but MATLAB ODE solver is giving me the following error:

```
Error in
@(t,x)[20000/NA*(-k1*x(1)*x(2)+k_n1*x(3)+krec*(1-fL)*x(4));
-k1*x(1)*x(2)+k_n1*x(3)-keR*x(2)+krec(1-fR)*x(5)+Vs;
k1*x(1)*x(2)-(k1+keC)*x(3);keC*x(2)-(kdegL*fL+krec*(1-fL))*x(4);
keR*x(2)+keC*x(3)-(kdegR*fR+krec(1-fR))*x(5)]

Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options,
varargin);

Error in cmp_2_bme (line 49)
[t, var] = ode45(f1, [0 30], [0, NR, 0, 0, NRi]);
```

My code is the following:

```
k1 = 7.2*10^7;
k_n1 = 0.3;
keR = 0.03;
keC = 0.30;
krec = 0.08;
kdegR = 0.0022;
kdegL = 0.01;
fR = 0.2;
fL = 0.05;
NA = 6.0221409*10^23;
NR = 0.5*10^5;
Vs = 10.2421
NRi = 2.3277e+04

f1 = @(t, x) [1/NA*(-k1*x(1)*x(2)+k_n1*x(3)+krec*(1-fL)*x(4)); ...
    -k1*x(1)*x(2)+k_n1*x(3)-keR*x(2)+krec(1-fR)*x(5)+Vs;...
    k1*x(1)*x(2)-(k1+keC)*x(3); ...
    keC*x(2)-(kdegL*fL+krec*(1-fL))*x(4);...%Nli
    keR*x(2)+keC*x(3)-(kdegR*fR+krec(1-fR))*x(5)] %Nri

[t, var] = ode45(f1, [0 30], [0, NR, 0, 0, NRi]);
```

I am unsure why the error is referring to ODE151I when I am using ODE45.

Thank you!

Comment: My equations are represented as the anonymous function f1, each equation is separated by a semicolon

Comment: Ok, what I see is, that some `*`are missing, in line 2 and 5, after `krec`. For me the system is running, but takes very long to calculate.

Comment: As @J_F has mentioned, the anonymous function that you are creating is incorrect. The error message says specifically `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`.